# db.SaveChanges() in loop doesn't save records after an error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, epplus, ora-00001

I want to import data from Excel to DataBase using EPPLUS. From here I took code: https://www.paragon-inc.com/resources/blogs-posts/easy_excel_interaction_pt6

```
using (var db = new DbEntities())
{
    for (var row = 2; row <= lastRow; row++)
    {
        var newRecord = new DB_USER
        {
            ID = Int32.Parse(worksheet.Cells[idColumn + row].Value.ToString()),
            FIRST_NAME = worksheet.Cells[firstNameColumn + row].Value.ToString(),
            LAST_NAME = worksheet.Cells[lastNameColumn + row].Value.ToString(),                               
        };

        db.DB_USER.Add(newRecord);
        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
            totalImported++;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            resultMessages.Add(string.Format("Error in line #{0}: {1}\n", row,
                ex.Message));
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine if data in excel are correct. Problem is if any record has invalid data. For example, we have 3 records in excel:

- ID: 21 **(ID not in base)**| FIRST NAME: John | LAST NAME: Cage
- ID: 1 **(ID is in base)** | FIRST NAME: Mei | LAST NAME: Blue
- ID: 25 **(ID not in base)** | FIRST NAME: Nick | LAST NAME: Siri

And in database is already record with `ID = 1`. So 1st and 3rd should save, but 2nd shouldn't. The problem is that only first record is saving, the rest (2nd and 3rd) will get an error. I don't know why? Maybe because it's one transaction or what? It's weird. Can anyone tell me what should I do to save 1st and 3rd record? Not only 1st in this case?

---

Error:

> ORA-00001: unique constraint primary key violated

what doesn't make any sense in 3rd record...

Comment: Specifically what error do you receive?  We can't really help you if you leave out critical information.

Comment: @mason, Edited, now you can see an error but still no sense

Comment: @DiPix: Did you get this working?

Comment: @MikaelPuusaari, Yes, why are you asking?

Comment: Oh, since the question is still open, if anyone gave you the answer, mark it as the answer, otherwise if you found the answer yourself, add the answer and mark your answer as the answer so the question might be closed :)

Comment: I made it in different way. I used temporary list (for correct records), after loop i was saving records from that list.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do a check in the database to see if there already is a user in the database with a specific ID and only do the insert if the user doesn't exist:

```
  bool exists = db.DB_USER.Where(u => u.ID == newRecord.ID).Any();

    if(!exists)
    {
        //Do the insert
    }
```

Comment: Of course I can, but what if there will be more complicated Foreignkeys?

Comment: Well usually foreign key references don't cause insert issues,like if you had a property on your user object called UserTypeID,You can insert as many users as you like with UserTypeID=1.You're getting an error because of a primary key violation so i gave you a solution for the problem you have

Comment: You are right, but what if in excel data will be string instead int in ID column? Try catch will handle with this. In your solution I have to handling with this using linq. You know what i mean?

Comment: no i have no idea what you mean.Instead of having all the what ifs just fix one problem first.Which is the primary key violation that i gave you the solution for and if you get any further errors try fix them afterwards

Comment: If it is a string that you need to cast to int before handling it, you just Int.Parse(ID) and if it is an int you need to cast to string you use ID.Tostring()

Answer (score 0):

You may find yourself in a situation where another other constraint than PK is violated.
This has potential to greatly increase the effort to validade all data prior to add/update.
For these scenarios where you can't simply check if the record already exists, i figured it out that once an error like this occurs, EF core continues throwing error because it keeps the entity state as "Modified".

Specifically in your case, try this:

```
        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
            totalImported++;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            resultMessages.Add(string.Format("Error in line #{0}: {1}\n", row,
                ex.Message));
            db.Entry(db.DB_USER).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn´t set ID at all in code. In the database, set the ID to autoincrement.. of course still have it in your model, but not in your logic

This way, you won´t need to think about handling the ID, but instead let the entity framework handle it

anyway, here are ideas on how to change your code:

```
        using (var db = new DbEntities())
            {
                foreach (user in db)
                {
                    var userExists = db.DB_USER.Where(u => u.ID == user.ID);

                    if(!userExists)
                    {
                        var newUser = new DB_USER
                        {
                                ID = Int32.Parse(worksheet.Cells[idColumn + row].Value.ToString()),
                                FIRST_NAME = worksheet.Cells[firstNameColumn + row].Value.ToString(),
                                LAST_NAME = worksheet.Cells[lastNameColumn + row].Value.ToString(),                               
                        };

                        try
                        {
                            db.DB_USER.Add(newUser);
                            db.SaveChanges();
                            totalImported++;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                             resultMessages.Add(string.Format("Error in line #{0}: {1}\n", row,
                             ex.Message));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Still my guess is that since your code in the question is starting on the third row(that seemed to hade ID 21
before you changed it, it might have lead you to think it was the first row that worked fine.

If you refresh your database there probably already is an entry in the database with ID 21 and after you changed
it to 25, and ran the code you probably now have one with 25 too and are getting the same error again.

I added a foreach loop to the code and a check for the entries existence, so the code should avoid the primary
key violation.

I also move this inside the try-catch block:

```
db.DB_USER.Add(newUser);
```

Comment: It's not the answer I expected. Because it's not my database and I can't change structure.

Comment: ok, the reason second and third is giving an error is probably because they already exist.. first row doesn´t exist at first, but when you create it, the third cant be added since you already added a row with that ID in the first row.

And as you pointed out the second row ID already existed beforehand

Oh you updated the question to include the error now.. it is a primary key violation, and the primary key is probably ID.. you can´t add rows with a primary key that already exists so you need to check if it exists first before trying to add the row

Comment: Ohh there was mistake in post above. 1st and 3rd record has diffrent ID and in base aren't them.

Comment: you still need to check if each row ID already exists in the database before you add them, since you seem to have a primary key in the database and by looking at your data and code, the primary key seems to be the ID column.. you cant add a primary key that already exists, otherwise you make a primary key violation that the database will not accept

Comment: I rewrote your code and added the changes(I don´t have access to visual studio atm so I had to write from memory and the code might be prone to mistakes, they shouldn´t be hard for you to fix though), trying to explain the reasoning behind the changes as easily as possible. Also, instead of writing the entire exception messages, the .NET framework comes with very good possibilities to catch nice exceptions with the innerException, there are great tutorials on it on youtube